# Convert Timestamp to DateTime in SQL (Google Big Query)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a timestamp into a datetime object in SQL (I'm using Google Big Query).

Here's what the timestamp column looks like — each row contains a 10 digit integer.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type) to me...

Comment: It's a unix timestamp (# of seconds since January 1st 1970)

Answer (score 2):

You want `timestamp_seconds()`:

```
select timestamp_seconds(time_stamp) as utc_timestamp
```

Your column looks like a Unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.